# Reusing actions in symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

Let's say we have an Article model and a Comment model.

```
Article:
  columns:
    body: text

Comment:
  columns:
    article_id: integer
    message: text
  relations:
    Article:
      local: article_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Comments
```

And we generate 2 models based on "article" and "comment" route collections:

```
article:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    module: article
    model: Article

comment:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    module: comment
    model: Comment
```

So, we basically have 2 cruds for each model. Now, in article's show action I would like to display an article, it's related comments and a form to add a comment.

```
class articleActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->article = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    $this->comments = Doctrine::getTable('Comment')->findAllByArticleId ($this->article->getId());
    $this->form = new CommentForm();

  }
}
```

The question is how can I reuse comment/new and comment/create actions when posting comments in article/show action? Is this the right way to organise the code?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to with comment/new and comment/create?

Comment: I see. Well, as a minimum, move the comment creation code inside the comment model so it becomes accessible anywhere: $comment->saveThisCommentThroughMyModel($data). Not really sure what else to say based on what you've posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse actions, it could be possible that you need a component.
Component are similar to partials, but you use a component when you have to add some logic to it (like the code you use in the action of comment/new or comment/create).

> A component is like an action, except
>   it's much faster. The logic of a
>   component is kept in a class
>   inheriting from sfComponents, located
>   in an actions/components.class.php
>   file. Its presentation is kept in a
>   partial.

[check here the docs of Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer) :

the docs are for Symfony 1.2, I use that in Symfony 1.4 without problems

I am really sure that a Component is what you are looking for.